# Passenger door unlocks the whole car when you pull on handle

Tags: ford, locks, falcon

It's an Australian 1999 Ford Falcon. The car locks and unlocks fine. Everything runs fine. The only problem is when the car is locked, if you pull on the **exterior** passenger door handle, the whole car unlocks. The whole car makes that click sound, as if you pressed the unlock button on the remote.

I'm pretty savvy with electronics repair, and I'm assuming this is an electronic issue. I just have no idea how to access anything. How would I go about finding where these components are in the car? Is this feasible to fix on my own? I don't have a lot of money to properly see anybody about this.

Thanks!

Comment: What have been changed or how did this start to happen,  does the handle open the door or just unlocks .

Comment: my guess is the door is not locking ( the lock is supposed to disable the exterior handle ) so if you pull it it act as if it is opened from the inside .

Comment: It's been like this since I bought it used about a year ago. Pulling on the handle both unlocks the car and opens the door.

Comment: Do you mean pull on the exterior handle or the interior handle @geekman?

Comment: @GdD the exterior handle

Comment: That would concern me too @geekman!

Comment: That means it doesn't lock that door,  does it have any visual indication for the lock ?

Comment: @Chebhou no it doesn't. The driver door is the only door with one.

Comment: Just a thought @geekman, if you sit inside with the doors locked and pull the passenger **inside** handle do the doors unlock?

Comment: So you should check the lock mechanism inside the door , I had faulty one in fiesta and is mostly plastic parts which got broken.

Comment: @GdD probably it will open even if locked correctly, on the fiesta the inside handle is separate from the outside handle and it doesn't get disabled by the lock.

Comment: The question is whether pulling the inside passenger handle unlocks **all** the doors @Chebhou, not just the passenger door.

Comment: My understanding is the car will unlock if it detects that any door is open. Same as when you try to lock the car with one door open it will just unlock again.

Comment: @GdD all doors unlock when you pull on the passenger door

Comment: It's the external handle I'm talking about. Sorry. I assumed it was normal for interior handles to unlock the car

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the OP's comment all doors unlock when the **inside** passenger door handle is pulled. This is pretty normal on cars these days, it's a convenience thing.

If the door only unlocked when you pulled the outside handle then I'd say it was tripping the same sensor as the inside handle and it could be electronic, but the fact that it opens the door as well points to a different problem.  I suspect what's happening is that there's an issue with the door mechanism where the lock does not disable external the handle, in other words it's mechanical, not electrical in nature. From a quick Google search it looks like the door actuators on those Fords are known for issues, and refurbs are easy to find and install.

Comment: Thanks! I looked up the actuator stuff, and I found a video of a guy explaining how the faulty actuator causes this exact problem, and how to replace it. It's fairly cheap, so I'm going to order that part and attempt to replace it!

Comment: Good luck @geekman, there's few more satisfying things than solving your own car problems.

Answer (score 1):

If indeed it is only when the internal handle is pulled I'd say the fault lies with the drivers internal handle for NOT unlocking the car when pulled.  If it's the outside handle something is obviously wrong.